Did Buckaroo Banzai influence the Flux Capacitor design in Back to the Future?
A few weeks ago I rewatched Back to the Future and then last night I rewatched The Adventures of Buckaroo Banzai Across the 8th Dimension.
In the opening scenes of Buckaroo with the jet car, we are briefly shown an equilateral triangular instrument that has pulsing lines emanating from each vertex, with all 3 meeting in the center of the triangle.

Supplied by blobbymcblobby
In Back to the Future, the key instrument is the Flux Capacitor, which while is in a square case, has 3 pulsing white lines emanating from what could be considered the vertices of an equilateral triangle, and meeting in the middle.

Cropped from By Dwurban - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=116834907
Both devices involve inter-dimensional transportation (physical, or time).  But the main difference between the design of these two devices is that Buckaroo's points upwards, while Doc's points downwards.  However, the similarity between the two is very suspicious.
Given the timing of the releases (Buckaroo in 1984, BttF in 1985), did Buckaroo Bonzai influence the design of the flux capacitor?

Heres a picture of the device in TAoBBAt8D: https://i.sstatic.net/wiNlIWjY.png

@blobbymcblobby Thanks for that.  But where did you get it so that I can give the correct credit?

i screen capped it about 2 and a half minutes ago... (Apparently the question was asked 14 years ago... so it has been noticed... )

@blobbymcblobby Am I duping?  I tried searching before posting

ah no, i meant the net in general, not on SE.

Also, why is there a watermelon there?

@blobbymcblobby I thought the overthruster was the small device that was carried around that the Red Lectoids were after?

you are right actually, was searching around for a name

@blobbymcblobby And the watermelon is still a mystery

1998 reboot tv series test by the vfx guys behind Star Trek: Voyager and Babylon 5: https://youtu.be/2-4Gc2BGkhk

mentioned briefly in podcast https://youtu.be/eLydQW5uTIU at 1:03:22

This is a fanpage I think, so not a great source, but claims a copy, half-way down: https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/youve-probably-never-seen-these-back-to-the-future-images-before-749958

https://thewanderingcompany.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/banzai-future/ another

It's unclear
The "Flux Capacitor" existed in some form going back to the first draft of Back to the Future, written in 1981:

Brown takes on the characteristics of a tour guide as he explains the machine.
PROF. BROWN: The Power Converter, now operating at peak efficiency, channels energy into the Flux Capacitor, which releases several jigowatts [sic] in a fraction of a millisecond. Electron acceleration takes place here...and the result is the temporal displacement beam you saw a few moments ago. The entire process is triggered when I release the rope.
Back to the Future: The Ultimate Visual History, page 18

My source for this, Back to the Future: The Ultimate Visual History, includes an illustration of the Flux Capacitor on this page, but it appears to be a reproduction of Doc Brown's notebook from the final film. It doesn't appear that a visual design for it existed for the first or second drafts.
For the third draft, dated July 11th, 1984, storyboards are included showing elements that would appear in the finished film, such as the DeLorean and a speedometer reading 88 mph. There's also some sketches by writer Bob Gale of designs for the Flux Capacitor, including a caltrops shape that resembles the final design.
Since Buckaroo Banzai was released in August 1984, it's unclear what awareness Bob Gale would have had of the film at the time he was writing the third draft. At the very least, he seems to have sketched a Y-shape before its theatrical release, but I haven't been able to find any indication whether he'd seen the trailer, seen an early copy of the film, solidified his designs after watching it later, etc.
He did mention in a 2015 interview that he met Christopher Lloyd through a co-producer who worked on both films, so he at least had some awareness of Buckaroo Banzai while working on Back to the Future:

Now, for us, it was just about, “Hey, Family Ties is funny, this kid’s got talent. He’s a crack-up and he’s the perfect guy for us.” So we didn’t care about that. And Christopher Lloyd too, he’d started in movies—One Flew Over the Cuckoo’s Next I believe was his first picture—but then he ends up on Taxi playing Reverend Jim for four or five years, so he was really known as Reverend Jim. But he kept doing character parts and interesting things in the movies and he had been in a movie called The Adventures of Buckaroo Banzai – who my co-producer, Neil Canton, was a co-producer on – and he knew Chris and said, “You guys gotta meet Chris.” So we met Chris.
https://thehundreds.com/blogs/bobby-hundreds/bob-gale-interview

Contemporary reviews also seemed to assume BTTF was directly referencing BB:

You might hope from this opening that we’re in for another “Buckaroo Banzai,” a movie crammed with so much visual and verbal invention and character detail that it almost burst. No such luck.
There aren’t enough bits of lovely inventiveness to pad out the gimmick that McFly is accidentally sent back 30 years in the professor’s time-warp car (another nod to “Buckaroo Banzai”), a plutonium-powered DeLorean. More about the plutonium later. McFly arrives in the middle of his parents’ senior year at high school.
"Movie Review: An Underpowered Trip 'Back to the Future'", Los Angeles Times


Yes, Canton is frequently cited as the man straddling the two, but there is never more detail than that. Theres something else about the number 88 also being a nod to BB (BB88 is the name of the car iirc), but its unlikely theres ever going to be any kind of confirmation one way or another it seems.
